# Snapshot extension registration failed and Snapshot extension registration failed docker image bsc:1.2.5

Tags: bsc, rpc, binance-smart-chain, full-node

Good Day Team

I have used the following latest docker image to run a node

**ghcr.io/bnb-chain/bsc:1.2.5**

I start up my docker container using the following

**docker run -v
(pwd)/data/node:/bsc/node -p 8545:8545 --rm --name bsc-mainnet -it ghcr.io/bnb-chain/bsc:1.2.5**

however i cannot connect to any peers and sync my node which is running successfully

**t=2023-06-15T14:26:35+0000 lvl=info msg="Looking for peers" peercount=0 tried=37 static=30
t=2023-06-15T14:26:43+0000 lvl=eror msg="Bsc extension Handshake failed" peer=4ee5da04 err=EOF
t=2023-06-15T14:26:43+0000 lvl=eror msg="Bsc extension Handshake failed" peer=1b104cdb err=EOF
t=2023-06-15T14:26:44+0000 lvl=eror msg="Bsc extension Handshake failed" peer=c7ae85f4 err=EOF
t=2023-06-15T14:26:45+0000 lvl=info msg="Looking for peers" peercount=0 tried=126 static=30
t=2023-06-15T14:26:48+0000 lvl=warn msg="Snapshot extension registration failed" peer=2b236036 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
t=2023-06-15T14:26:55+0000 lvl=info msg="Looking for peers" peercount=1 tried=64 static=30
t=2023-06-15T14:27:05+0000 lvl=info msg="Looking for peers" peercount=1 tried=55 static=30
t=2023-06-15T14:27:15+0000 lvl=info msg="Looking for peers" peercount=2 tried=69 static=30
t=2023-06-15T14:27:17+0000 lvl=eror msg="Bsc extension Handshake failed" peer=49a51305 err=EOF
t=2023-06-15T14:27:18+0000 lvl=eror msg="Bsc extension Handshake failed" peer=0c22b0cf err=EOF
t=2023-06-15T14:41:17+0000 lvl=eror msg="Bsc extension barrier failed" id=4ee5da046a2380b9ff3593e4418aed90b30dda001529ef66f0e48519c30f7ea0 conn=staticdial err="peer wait timeout"**

I have also tried
**geth --datadir node init genesis.json**

and

**geth --snapshot=false**

any assistance would be sincerely appreciated thank you team

Answer (score 0):

I Have Resolved the Issue and was missing the --syncmode command

[image: SUCCESS]